# How do I open the case for a HP ENVY Notebook - 17-n152sa (ENERGY STAR)?

Tags: laptop-repair, repair, hp-envy

I have unscrewed every screw I can find and looked online for help, including the HP support and maintenence pages, YouTube and other obvious sources and scoured some web pages but for some reason can't find a single guide for this model. There are other HP Laptop disassembly guides for other HP laptops, which don't have the same case design.

Once I've unscrewed every screw, and taken them out and put them aside, the base is still stuck to the case as if it's glued on, and I've pulled at it but I'm afraid to break it, it shouldn't be this hard to separate.

There is no seperate drive cover, the base is just one piece of aluminium. How to I take off the case to replace the HDD for an SDD?

Pic of base below:

[Picture of base for illustrative purposes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5cNb.jpg)

Comment: There is a good chance it **is** glued on, or is being held by a "warranty void if seal is broken" sticker. Do you have a pry tool?

Comment: Thanks, I don't.... do I need one, and where do I put it?

Comment: To be clear though, are you attempting to remove the panel on the very bottom or the panel that includes the keyboard? Here is the procedure for replacing the battery: http://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c04351268

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. It's actually the HDD I want to replace with an SDD. I've added a pic so you can see. I want to know how to take out the HDD?